# Подключение дополнения\генерация Sitemap в Silex

Tags: silex

Клиент задал задачку построить сайтмап в инете нашел вроде вменяемое дополнение: https://github.com/tommy-muehle/silex-sitemap-service-provider. Но при подключении не видит методов указанных в документации (автлоад вроде подключил файлы и провайдер) но хз. Может кто делал подобную задачу поделится опытом или поскажет решение вопроса. `$app->get('sitemap.xml', function () use ($app) { $host = $app['request']->getSchemeAndHttpHost(); $sitemap = $app['sitemap']; $sitemap->addEntry($host . '/', 1, 'yearly'); $entities = $app['repository.entity']->findAll(50000); foreach ($entities as $entity) { $entityLoc = $app['url_generator']->generate('entity', array('entity' => $entity->getId())); $sitemap->addEntry($host . $entityLoc, 0.8, 'monthly', $entity->getLastModified()); } return $sitemap->generate(); }) ->bind('sitemap');`

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема с указанной библиотекой? Может стоит привести небольшой кусочек кода с вашей попыткой ее использовать?

Comment: пробую подключить как сказано в документации но при дебаге в пхпсторме видно что  при попытке захода в замыкание `$app->get('sitemap.xml', function () use ($app) {` оно перескакивевает его и методы этого замыкания подсвечиваются как не найденые.

Comment: ` $app->get('sitemap.xml', function () use ($app) {

      $host = $app['request']->getSchemeAndHttpHost();

      $sitemap = $app['sitemap'];
      $sitemap->addEntry($host . '/', 1, 'yearly');

      $entities = $app['repository.entity']->findAll(50000);

      foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        $entityLoc = $app['url_generator']->generate('entity', array('entity' => $entity->getId()));
        $sitemap->addEntry($host . $entityLoc, 0.8, 'monthly', $entity->getLastModified());
      }

      return $sitemap->generate();
    })
    ->bind('sitemap');`

Comment: Перенесите код из комментариев в вопрос, читать невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятней всего представленный автором код подходит для версии silex ^2.0.
   Одна из возможных реализаций с этой библиотекой для версии silex 1.3.5:

```
$app->get('sitemap.xml', function () use ($app) {
        foreach ($app['routes'] as $pattern) {
            $app['sitemap']->addEntry($app['request']->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . $pattern->getPattern(), 0.8, 'daily', new \DateTime());
        }
        return $app['sitemap']->generate();
    })
    ->bind('sitemap');
```